# set Banner in expected time zone

Tags: angular, timezone

Trying to set banner with world wide same timing but not getting expected results.

In my project, I want to set an outage banner with some start date and end date. Currently, I am comparing system date with start and end date and displaying banner accordingly. Here an issue is with different time zones. For sync,I convert all 3 dates(start, sysDate and end dates) in UTC but its not working in CST time zone.

```
let startDate, endDate;
let sysDate = new Date();
this.sysDate= new Date(this.sysDate.toUTCString()).valueOf();
this.startDate = new Date(this.OutageDetails.startDate);
this.startDate= new Date(this.startDate.toUTCString()).valueOf();
this.endDate= new Date(this.OutageDetails.endDate);
this.endDate= new Date(this.endDate.toUTCString()).valueOf();
if(startDate<= this.sysDate && this.sysDate<=this.endDate())
{
  console.log('Show the banner');
}
```

//here, OutageDetails is file where I am fetching startDate and endDate

This is showing expected results for all UTC zones but not CST. I also tried with GMT as well but no success. Please let me know best possible solution for this.

Comment: I'd recommend using the the ```moment.js``` and ```moment-timezone``` libraries since they make working with Date objects a lot less irritating.

Answer (score -1):

please refer this two urls for better solutions:
1) https://momentjs.com/ 
2) https://momentjs.com/timezone/